# removing padding/gap from displaying ppt on UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

[image: Example]

In the example, between the slides of the PPT file, there is gray padding/gap which I don't want. I want the upcoming slide reside directly below the current slide without anything in between. Prefer solution is Swift.

Answer (score 0):

in webViewDidFinishLoad()

do this

```
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');var count = slides.length;for (var i = 1; i < count; i++) {var oldTop = slides[i].style.top;var newTop = parseInt(oldTop) - 5 * i + 'px';slides[i].style.top = newTop;}")
```